# How do I keep one page from a PDF as separate file in Python?

Tags: python

The code below splits the pages in a PDF file to multiple pdf files. However, I want only the second page from each file to split.

```
import os
from glob import glob
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
def splitPDF(file_name,output_dir=None):
    inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open(file_name , "rb"))
    num_pages = inputpdf.numPages
    for i in range(num_pages):
        output = PdfFileWriter()
        output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i))
        output_name = f"{os.path.basename(file_name.replace('.pdf',''))}{i+1}.pdf"
        if output_dir is None:
            output_name = os.path.join(output_dir, output_name)
        with open(output_name,'wb') as outputStream:
            output.write(outputStream)
    print(f"PDF: {file_name} has been splitted")
base_dir = r"path where the pdf files are stored in folder"
output_dir = r"path where i want to extract the file"
pdfs = os.path.join(base_dir,"*.pdf")
files = glob(pdfs)
for file in files:
    splitPDF(file,output_dir)
```

Could someone address this? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: This code was from Stackoverflow, just need some clarifications and update on the same

Comment: Just add `if condition` inside of the loop: For example `if i == 2:`

Comment: Do you mean `output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(1))`? No need for a loop...

Comment: Hi, it did work. thank you. But why am I not able to save the file in the output_dir. Like it's getting extracted only in the base_dir